# How can I play a midi file with .NET compact framework 2.0?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, c#-2.0, midi

I have tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229685(VS.80).aspx) but it does not work (even if I specify .wav file as an input). Also tried [this](http://inquisitorjax.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-play-sounds-c-20-compact.html) but still no sound. Trying to avoid .wav because they are BIG if you compare with midi.

I'm trying this with VS 2008 emulator. Is that the problem? Should I test on the real hardware?

What is the best way to play midi on the .NET compact framework 2.0 ??

Comment: You should be aware that it takes a lot more to play midis than to play wavs, i.e. virtual instruments and a mixer to start with.

Comment: I know but I expected to hear at least some output from the speakers. Nothing comes through, not even for wav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am just adding some information. It seems you have a misunderstanding about Midi format. Not like the Wave files the Midi file does not keep the actual "Sound". It just keeps a value mapped with the actual sound. We just use a synthesizer to regenerate the sound. As and example we may hear the same midi song differently with different synthesizers.

According to this synthesis of sound I guess it consumes the CPU more than a normal Wave file. Please have a look on this matter as well because you are trying to use the mobile devices with less resources.